# How can I obtain all font files for fonts I use in an Impress presentation?

Tags: fonts, automation, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress, document-automation

I want to have a(n installable) copy of all the fonts I use in a LibreOffice Impress presentation I'm writing. I don't think LibreOffice has any UI to make that happen, so I'm fine with doing it "on my own", e.g. by some script or Makefile which creates a tarball/zip of these. Still, even for that I would need to extract all of the files of fonts used, or to extract a list of fonts (or font families) used, then obtain the font files for those.

How can I make that happen? I'm mostly interested in GNU/Linux (any reasonable modern distribution) and in Windows + Cygwin. Windows-without-Cygwin may be interesting for other readers of this question.

**Note:**

- In case this matters, you may assume LibreOffice 5 and an `.odp` file (not working on a `.ppt`).
- In case this matters, you may assume I'll restrict myself to fonts which come in OpenType or TrueType files (`.ttf` or `.otf`), although I'd rather you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only relevant to `.odt` (Writer) documents, not to `.odp` (Impress) documents.

#### I need to extract a list of fonts

You can use the [TestFonts](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/testfonts) extension.

> Searches for all font faces used in writer document and compare it with fonts available in system. Reporting for missing font faces, all used fonts and get statistic available system fonts. You can look for font name from report. Dialog is modal with zoom button now.
>   Language: English, Czech, German, French.

Source [TestFonts](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/testfonts)

Confirmed as working in LibreOffice Writer Version: 5.2.4.2

**Sample Output**:

```
File: F:\test\test\test.odt

Missing fonts - found:  0 times

Direct formatting fonts - found:  0 times

Fonts assigned to used paragraph styles - found:  1 times
   Default Style              Liberation Serif          Regular 

Fonts assigned to used character styles - found:  0 times

Available system fonts - found:  449 times
```

...

Comment: Sorry, David, I had a typo - I meant to say I'm working on an `.odp`, not an `.odt`. Does the extension work on `.odp`s? The description you quoted mentions "writer document[s]".

Comment: @einpoklum Unfortunately not :/

Comment: Edited accordingly.